# convert backslashes to forward in batch files

Tags: bash, batch-file

whats the easiest way of converting all backslashes to forward in a path in a batch file, since I need to use bash for execution.

Comment: ... Wich one is it? Batch or Bash? Batch is for Windows, Bash is for Linux (and Mac?).

Comment: I am running batch(windows), need to build a make file using Bash( on windows, i have bash set up on the machine)

Comment: Ah, something lik Win-Bash, I presume?

So... You want to read a file (using MS-DOS Batch), and replace all occurances of \ to /. Is that correct?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
SET "string=D:\path\to\folder"
ECHO %string:\=/%
```

Basically, you need first to store the string value into an environment variable, then use the following template:

```
%variable:str1=str2%
```

to replace every occurrence of *`str1`* in *`variable`* with *`str2`*.

You can always remind yourself about this pattern by invoking `SET /?` from the command prompt.

Answer (score 2):

```
echo 'C:\Program Files\Program' | sed -e 's/\\/\//g'
```

Comment: I am getting a "sed: -e expression #1, char 8: unterminated `s' command" error

Comment: "echo 'C:\Program Files\Program' | sed -e s/\\/\//g" works good

Comment: Alternatively, to avoid the picket fence: `echo 'C:\Program Files\Program' | sed -e 's_\\_/_g'`