# Read a directory and escape backslashes from path

Tags: batch-file, path, escaping, backslash

I'm currently trying to read a directory and put files with escaping backslashes from the path.

Here is a part of the code :

```
for /r "Pictures" %%a in (*) do (
set var=%%a
echo %var:\=\\% >> pic.txt
)
```

I have `\=\\` in pic.txt but I want `H:\\Pictures\\pic1.jpg` in the output file.

I saw something similar [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6189771/convert-backslashes-to-forward-in-batch-files) but I can't have what I want.

Any idea ?

EDIT :

```
for /f "delims=" %%x in (pic.txt) do (
set var=%%x
echo %var:\=/% >> pic2.txt
)
```

I've got `\=/` for each ligne. I'm not far of the solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is related to Delayed Expansion. Solve it this way:

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /r "Pictures" %%a in (*) do (
set var=%%a
echo !var:\=\\! >> pic.txt
)
```

For further explanation, google for "delayed expansion" and/or read the section about it in `set /?` command.